# Return URL from file uploaded to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a function that makes an API request containing the URL of a new file I just uploaded to AWS S3.
And I have one function that only upload the file to S3.

I am having issues with returning this URL of the uploaded file.

Here is my code:

```
  myfunction(){
    let file; // assume the file is already set
    let filename; // assume the filename is already set

    let s3URL =  uploadFile(file, filename);
    console.log(s3URL); // this is returning a ManagedUpload object, I dont know how to get the URL from there
    makeAPIRequest(s3URL);
  }

  async uploadFile(file, fileName) {
    // S3 is from --> import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
    const s3 = new S3(
      {
        accessKeyId: 'myaccesskeyid',
        secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey',
        region: 'us-east-1'
      }
    );

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      Key: 'MyDirectory/' + fileName,
      Body: file
    };

    return await s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
      return data; // URL is here inside data.Location
    });
  }
```

Here is the SDK doc with the upload example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want your `uploadFile` function to return the data from the `s3.upload` callback, rather than the result of the call itself. You can do that by returning your own Promise, and resolving it with the data you need:

```js
  myfunction(){
    // ...

    // Remember to add `await` here
    const s3Data = await uploadFile(file, filename);
    const s3URL = s3Data.Location;
    
    // ...
  }

  async uploadFile(file, fileName) {
    // ...
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```